# Yii2 automatic login based on http headers

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm having a problem implementing an automatic login based on the NT user received in the http headers. (intranet website)

I've added the following code in the beforeAction of my yii\base\Controller.php

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{

     if (!Yii::$app->user->identity) {
        Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
        //the NT username received in the HTTP headers
        $ntnet = \app\models\Users::getNTNET();
        //var_dump($ntnet);
        $model = \app\models\Users::findOne(["LOWER(`user_name`)" => strtolower($ntnet)]);
        if (!is_null($model))
        Yii::$app->user->login($model);

    }       

    $event = new ActionEvent($action);
    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION, $event);
    return $event->isValid;
```

If I uncomment the var_dump($ntnet) line, it will work, and echo the name, if not, $ntnet will be null, same goes for the $model, if I var dump it (as well as $ntnet before that), it will output the entire user properties and login successfully, otherwise, it will be null, why is it? it makes no sense to me.

For instance - I've intentionally added a typo in the "LOWER()" function in to receive the SQL error and view the entire query being executed, and if var_dump($ntnet) is comment, it will produce the following,
As you can see the $ntnet parameter is empty:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION oncall.LOWaER does not exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWaER(`user_name`)=''
```

With var_dump($ntnet) the error will be as following:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION oncall.LOWaER does not exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWaER(`user_name`)='myusername'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check implementation `__debugInfo()` method  in `User` class or extendet classes, and add to question description and `User::getNTNET()` to.

Answer (score 0):

To get username and password from HTTP header,
Use 
`$username = \Yii::$app->request->authUser;` 
and `$password = \Yii::$app->request->authPassword;`

Also check the spelling of `lower()` function.  On your trace message, it's `LOWaER`.  It should be `LOWER`